# Multi-user gollum-wiki workflow

Tags: git, github, wiki, gollum-wiki

I installed gollum-wiki to serve as our labs wiki (14 members).  Since it is git based, I imagine the most logical workflow would be that every user has a local copy of the repository and whenever they make changes, would initiate a pull request? Any other workflow suggestions are appreciated.

Also, two more specific questions:

1. If I have a repository (e.g. mywiki) that I want to clone from bitbucket into the webserver and start using that as a starting point - do I need to use

   gollum --page-file-dir

   to specify gollum to use that folder for page creation?
2. Also, from the web-based editor, when I create a new page, .e.g. `page1`, I see `page1.md` created in the gollum directory under `/var/gollum` but when I create a page e.g. `pages/page2` to create a page in `pages` folder, I dont see the `pages` folder created anywhere in the webserver nor can I find the `pages.md` file. However I see the folder and the page in the web based wiki.

There must be something that I am doing wrong. Any inputs?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this still occur? Do you have some new observations?

Comment: It works as expected on my machine. Gollum version 2.5.0 and starting as Rack app under Pow

Comment: Thanks! I haven't checked again, as I could not get it working. Started working on deploying gitlab which has all the components. Will let you know once I try

Comment: @VijayIvaturi Yes, I wish Gollum had multi-user functionality. GitLab is a bit overkill if all you want is multi-user, Git-backed wiki functionality.